# How to make ajax editable cell?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have this index.html.erb file:

```
   <h3>Pažymiai</h3><br />
    Nuo: <%= @begining_of_week = Date.commercial(2011, 48, 1) %> 
    iki: <%= @end_of_week = Date.commercial(2011, 48, -1) %>
    <table class="macs">
    <tr>
    <th>Vardas, pavardė</th>
    <th>Dalykas</th>
    <% (@begining_of_week..@end_of_week).each do |d| %>
    <th class="calendar"><%= d.day %></th>
    <% end %>
    </tr>
    <% @students.each do |student| %>
        <tr>
            <td class="name" rowspan="<%= @subjects.count %>"><%=link_to(admin_student_path(student)) do %><%= student.name%><br /> <%= student.surname %><% end %></td>
            <% @subjects.each do |subject| %>
            <td class="subject"><%=subject.name%></td>
            <% (@begining_of_week..@end_of_week).each do |d| %>     
            <% @mac = Mac.where(:student_id => student.id, :subject_id => subject.id, :date => d) %>
            <% if @mac.blank? %> 
            <td class="calendar_mac" onclick="location.href='<%= new_admin_mac_path %>'"><center>
            </center>
            <%= link_to 'new_mac', new_admin_mac_path, :remote => true %>
            </td>
            <% else %>
            <% @mac.each do |mac| %>
            <td class="calendar_mac" onclick="location.href='<%= edit_admin_mac_path(mac) %>'"><center> 
            <%= mac.mac%>
            <% end %>
            <% end %>       
            </center></td>
            <% end %>
        </tr>   
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
    </table>
```

How to make if cell is empty to write new value, if cell has value make it editable, when click cell i want a popup window where you could edit or add new element to database. My table looks:
[image: my table now]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [best in place gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/best_in_place) and follow a sample screen cast by [ryanb](http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing) this might help you out